# Right align labels and float text to the left to make them appear on the same line in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[image]

```html
<form  class="form-horizontal" action="addtodatabase.php" class="form-inline" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
 <div class="container-fluid">

    
  <fieldset>
  <legend><h5>Security Department User Registration</h5></legend>
  
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-4 control-group">
   <label class="control-label" for="Firstname">First Name</label>
   <div class="controls">
   <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="firstname" placeholder="Text input"><br/>
   </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="col-xs-4 control-group">
   <label class="control-label" for="Secondname">Second Name</label>
   <div class="controls">
   <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm"  name="secondname" placeholder="Text input"><br/>
   </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="col-xs-4 control-group">
   <label class="control-label"for="location">Dpt./Location</label>
   <div class="controls">
   <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm"  name="location"  placeholder="Text input">
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

> `In my form I get label  at the top and next line field .Since I have used row three of them are in the same row but I want label then followed by field .`
>
> Right now I am not able to get the field in horizontal line `First Name,Second Name,Dpt./Location.`
>
> LABEL AT TOP AND FIELD AT THE BOTTOM
>
> I HAVE LABEL OF DIFFERENT LENGTH I WANT IT TO BE ARRANGED PROPERLY.

**what changes I need to do**

> In my form I want both label and text field to be horizontal `label to be at right side and followed by  text field` 
>   I have many other fields  but they don`t align properly because of  label being lengthy .
>
> `I want all the label both long and short to be aligned properly immediately followed by text field.`
>
> I  pic u can see label (`name` and `DOB`) is followed by text field   are in the  same line 
>   This is what I want to do

Comment: Try to create a code snippet here, much easier for us to look :)

Comment: Have you tried Bootstrap's .form-inline class?

Comment: @RachelS yes i have

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the following link and I think you will find a solution for your question.

https://jsfiddle.net/wLxf6cnn/

Note: Make the viewport larger than 768px wide to see that all of the form elements are inline, left aligned, and the labels are alongside.

```
<form action="addtodatabase.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <legend>
          <h5>Security Department User Registration</h5>
        </legend>

        <div class="row form-inline">
          <div class="col-xs-4 form-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="Firstname">First Name
              <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="firstname" placeholder="Text input">
              <br/>
            </label>
          </div>

          <div class="col-xs-4 form-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="Secondname">Second Name
              <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="secondname" placeholder="Text input">
              <br/>
            </label>
          </div>

          <div class="col-xs-4 form-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="location">Dpt./Location
              <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="location" placeholder="Text input">
            </label>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you want something like this.

**take a look at the example**

```css
label {
   
    clear:left;
    text-align:right;
    padding-right:10px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<form action="addtodatabase.php" class="form-inline" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
 <div class="container-fluid">

    
  <fieldset>
  <legend><h5>Security Department User Registration</h5></legend>
  
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-4 form-group">
   <label class="control-label" for="Firstname">First Name
   
   <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="firstname" placeholder="Text input"><br/></label>
  
  </div>
  
  <div class="col-xs-4 form-group">
   <label class="control-label" for="Secondname">Second Name
   
   <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm"  name="secondname" placeholder="Text input"><br/></label>
   </div>
 
  
  <div class="col-xs-4 form-group">
   <label class="control-label"for="location">Dpt./Location
  
   <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm"  name="location"  placeholder="Text input"></label>
   </div>
  </div>
```